# GcmTaskService and threading

Tags: android, android-task

1. Does `onRunTask` run on a different thread?
   This is not clearly explained in the documentation here https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmTaskService. Or Is there other documentation I should look at?
2. The documentation says:

> Per service, two tasks with the same tag will never execute
>   concurrently. Should a newly-scheduled task arrive while an existing
>   task is still running, the new task will be dropped. **In addition,
>   different tasks may be scheduled concurrently, each invoked in a
>   separate thread, if their schedules overlap**. It is up to you to ensure
>   thread safety when scheduling multiple tasks.

I'm confused about this part:

> In addition, different tasks may be scheduled concurrently, each invoked in a
>   separate thread, if their schedules overlap.

Does this still refer to a task with same tag, or is it referring to two tasks with different tags?

I was thinking it's referring to two tasks with different tags, because it says `Per service, two tasks with the same tag will never execute concurrently`.

In other words, my understanding is there will never be two tasks with same tag executing concurrently, but two tasks with different tags can be executed concurrently. Is this correct?